# How can I do a "Group by" with a Dictionary object?

Tags: c#, dictionary, group-by, linq-to-objects

In C#, I have a Dictionary object which stores one integer value and one decimal value.

```
Dictionary<decimal,int> objDict = new Dictionary<decimal,int>();
```

and the values are

```
   12  1
   23  1
   14  1
   6   2
   9   2
   16  3
   -4  3
```

I want to do a group by on this using LINQ, so that I will get the max value. The expected output is

```
   23  1
    9  2
   16  3
```

How to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to do a group by or a Max?

Comment: Max. grouped by the first column

Comment: A `Dictionary` doesn't allow for duplicate keys, so your description doesn't seem accurate. What type of object is it exactly? Maybe you can show us how this object is setup with some code.

Comment: What Dictionary you have? `Dictionary<int,decimal>` or `Dictionary<someKey,Tuple<int,decimal>>` or `Dictionary<someKey,yourClassWithIntAndDecimalValue>` ?

Comment: Which column is the key? I assume the second one because otherwise you'd wipe out values.

Comment: You wont be able to use Dictionary in this case, beacuse key must be unique. Use `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,decimal>>` or `IEnumerable<Tuple<int,decimal>>`

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. As @Ahmad pointed out, a key is unique in a dictionary. You will not have multiple values with the same key!

Answer (score 3):

```
var query = yourDictionary.GroupBy(x => x.Value,
                                   (k, g) => new {
                                                     Max = g.Max(x => x.Key),
                                                     Value = k
                                                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemCount2NumberMap = yourDictionary.GroupBy(item=>item.Value).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Max(y=>y.Key));
```